# What are these triangle shapes on the face that appear after i bisect this mesh

Tags: texturing

[image: Triangle Artifacts]

I want to create an animation of opening of a human bone but after bisecting it appears like this. When ever I apply any material or texture it shows in some part of these font faces and some part appears gray.

How can I fix these?

Comment: Hello, it looks like bad shading, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: "z-fighting" is the term to look for.